# Mathematica not recognizing expressions are real

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I see no problem with following calculation.

```
Refine[ComplexExpand[b I /(a + b I)], {Element[a, Reals], Element[b, Reals]}]
```

> ```
> (I a b)/(a^2 + b^2) + b^2/(a^2 + b^2)
> ```

The real and imaginary parts are nicely separated.

However, the next calculations are confusing to me.  Please explain how I get the output.  Should I get

```
b^2/(a^2 + b^2)
```

as I declared a and b are real?

```
Refine[
  Re[(I a b)/(a^2 + b^2) + b^2/(a^2 + b^2)], {Element[a, Reals], Element[b, Reals]}]
```

> ```
> -a b Im[1/(a^2 + b^2)] + b^2 Re[1/(a^2 + b^2)]
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also tell Mathematica that `a^2 + b^2` is not zero.

```
Refine[
  Re[(I a b)/(a^2 + b^2) + b^2/(a^2 + b^2)], {a, b} ∈ Reals && a^2 + b^2 > 0]
```

> ```
> b^2/(a^2 + b^2)
> ```

Comment: If a^2 +b^2 is zero, the outputs are also not valid.  The 'ComplexExpand[]' function behave as I expected.  The 'Re[]' function seems weird to me, still.  The 'Im[1/(a^2 + b^2)]' is always zero if a and b are real provided  nonzero a^2 +b^2 .